# How to INSERT a result set multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to enter employee id's (`Emp_ID`) into the `schedule` table 30 times. The employee id's are being pulled from the `employee` table. It will work on the first loop but then breaks on the second. The error I get is

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\server\roster\dates.php on line 110"

Line 110 is the `while` loop. I can only assume this is happening because the result set is being emptied, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
<?php
//Select all of the current Employees by ID number
$sql = ("SELECT Emp_ID FROM employee");

//Run a check on the query to make sure it worked.
//if it failed then print the error.
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
die('There was an error getting the Emp_ID from the employee table [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
}

//Loop through the results...
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    //...and for each employee ID, enter it into the table 30 times.
    for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++ )
        {
        $sql = ("INSERT INTO schedule (Emp_ID) VALUES ('" . $row['Emp_ID'] . "')");

            //Run a check on the query to make sure it worked.
            //if it failed then print the error.
            if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql))
            {
            die('There was an error inserting the Emp_ID into the schedule [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
            }
        }       
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result` is already in use on `while` loop and you can't use same name inside the loop that will overwrite the current values of `$result`

Change the `$result` to different variable name `$result_insert` (I mean after the insert query)

`if(!$result_insert = $mysqli->query($sql))`

Comment: Not only were you lightening fast at answering this, you were dead on! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting $result variable. Use different variable name in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if condition, you are using the same $result variable, which is changing its type to a non object. chnage its name to something else.